# How to get the current ble connection state established in other apps?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I understand that I can get the current ble connection state established in my app like below.

```
// I establish the connection in my app.
val address = "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
val device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address)
device.connectGatt(MyApplication.appContext, false, gattCallback)

// Then I can get the current connection state
val state = bluetoothManager.getConnectionState(device, BluetoothProfile.GATT) // state is BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED
```

If the connection is established in other apps, `bluetoothManager.getConnectionState(device, BluetoothProfile.GATT)` return BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED in my app.

My question is that can I get the current ble connection state established in other apps like in my app?